Motor makes a very strong grinding noise under specific conditions
I recently bought an EUENI FXH009, very affordable chinese ebike. I'm very happy with it, it's very nice for the price but there seems to be some kind of problem with the motor.
When accelerating between 25 to 30-ish km/h it makes an extremely loud grinding noise almost like an angle grinder. It doesn't push/pull or vibrate or slow down the acceleration - there are no other physical effects other than sound. If I ignore the sound and continue accelerating once I reach about 35 km/h and above the sound disappears. It also happens sometimes when accelerating on an incline around 15-20km/h but very briefly. I tried lifting the rear tire and accelerating and the noise does not appear then, so it supposedly only happens under load. I checked the motor with my hand after riding about 30km full throttle and it was warm to the touch so no overheating.
I got it used off of another person locally but it only had 20km on the clock and all the components show no signs of usage so I am keen to believe it has almost not been used - problem is I don't have contact with the original seller to ask them for advice.
I'm sorry if it's a bit too long but I'm trying to give as much information as possible to assist anyone trying to assist me.

Are you 100% sure it’s the hub making the noise? Might be brake rotor noise. Try locating a local e-bike motor repair service. Local meaning your country in general as you’ll need to ship them the back wheel.
